# smbclient copy from linux to windows (SMB)

Tags: bash, shell-script, file-copy, smbclient

Want to copy directory from linux machine to windows (SMB) with shell script.

```
[user@host home]$ smbclient -W WORKGROUP --user='admin%admin$123' -c "put /data/directory" "//192.168.1.1/share"
Domain=[mydomain] OS=[Windows Server] Server=[Windows Server]
/data/directory does not exist
[user@host home]$ cd /data/directory
/data/directory
[user@host directory]$ ll
File1
File2
..
```

Here is the issues:

- Not accept password even when I use (`-N`)
- even try this `--user=admin%admin$123`

When I remove password from command and shell ask me password it works!

FYI: for transferring directory between Windows and Linux I read about curl, and SSH daemon on windows for scp, do you have any recommendation or simple way, without require additional service on Windows or package on Linux?

Comment: I guess the `“` and `”` characters in your code used to be `"`, while the `—` characters were originally `-`. Am I right? If so, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/535876/edit) your question, replacing the characters that were not in the command you actually tried. It will help other users in ruling out possible issues.

Comment: 1) Are you sure your `smbclient` accepts a `--pass` option? (My does not). 2) Your issue may depend on the characters in your password (e.g `$`). You should single-quote the password string, to input it literally, or double-quote it, if you store it in a variable. Possibly `--user='admin%admin$123'`.

Comment: 1-in address of source file I have under score _ , how can I define addresses like this? Would you please write simple example of my command.

Comment: 2-you right read man of smbclient not mention about it. I try user='admin%admin$123' seems work, but seems not get my source address and give me not find source address!

Comment: Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/535876/edit) you question and add it the exact error message you are seeing. If possible, copy/paste both it and the full command you are trying (after obfuscating sensitive parts as passwords, of course).

Comment: Done please check post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy `/data/directory` on Linux so that a copy of it will appear as `\\192.168.1.1\share\directory` on Windows, then perhaps this command should do the job:

```
smbclient -W WORKGROUP --user='admin%admin$123' -c "lcd /data;recurse;mput directory" "//192.168.1.1/share"
```

Rationale:

- to copy a directory with its contents, you'll need to enable recursion with `recurse` and use `mput` as you will be copying multiple files. The regular `put` command will only transfer **one file** at a time, optionally giving the copy a different name at the destination.
- by first using `lcd`, the recursion is limited so that the copy won't become `\\192.168.1.1\share\data\directory` but just `\\192.168.1.1\share\directory`

Comment: seems not work!

`[user@host home]$ smbclient -W WORKGROUP --user='admin%admin$123' -c "lcd /data;recurse;mput directory" "//192.168.1.1/share"
-bash: recurse: command not found
-bash: mput: command not found`

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: The error message indicates the `recurse` and `mput` commands were somehow handled by the `bash` shell, not by the `smbclient` command. Did you accidentally omit a quote character at some point?

Comment: No, did you run your command successfully ?

Comment: Yes, I did. If your version of `smbclient` starts displaying prompts like `Put directory directory?`, you'll need to add `prompt;` to the `-c` command string before the `mput`, i.e. `$ smbclient -W WORKGROUP --user='admin%admin$123' -c "lcd /data;recurse;prompt;mput directory" "//192.168.1.1/share"`. It is important that the argument to the `-c` option is quoted, as the semi-colon is a command separator for the shell. Your error message indicates the shell parsed everything up to the first semicolon as one command, `recurse` as another command etc. So you failed to quote the option argument.